# How to add different values of error bars in both y- directions from a csv file in pgfplots?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplotstable, error-bars

I have a working code. Unfortunately though, it appears as if the error bars are being added twice. Once in blue and once in gray. I don't understand what is causing this. How can I fix it?
Here is the data file [data.csv](https://easyupload.io/386g1k).

```
\documentclass[crop,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \begin{axis}[
    width=\linewidth,
    legend style={nodes={scale=0.5, transform shape}, anchor=north east}, 
    xmin = 0, xmax = 30,
    ymin = 45, ymax =65,
    xlabel= {Time[s]},
    ylabel={ST},
    error bars/y dir=both,
    error bars/y explicit]
    
    \addplot+[ color=blue, mark=., thin, error bars/.cd, error mark options={gray}]
    table[col sep=comma, x=Base_T, y=Base_ST, y error=Base_SD] {data.csv} ;
    \addlegendentry{Baseline}
    
    \addplot+[ color=green,mark=., thin]
    table[col sep=comma, x=pn_T, y=pn_ST] {data.csv} ;  
    \addlegendentry{Test1};   
 \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

This results in the following diagram:
[image]

Comment: Unrelated: When using PGFPlots, remember to always set the `compat` level - see my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this is the result you expect:

```
\begin{filecontents}{data.csv}
Base_T, Base_ST, Base_SD
8,48,1
15,50,2
20,55,2
\end{filecontents}
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
xmin = 0, xmax = 30,
ymin = 45, ymax =65,
xlabel= {Time[s]},
ylabel={ST},
error bars/y dir=both,
error bars/y explicit,
]
\addplot[blue, mark=none, error bars/error mark options={gray, rotate=90}]
table[col sep=comma, x=Base_T, y=Base_ST, y error=Base_SD] {data.csv};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Graph with gray error bars]